Closed, bounded and noncompact set
I am referring to Exercise 7.4.17 from the book Basic Analysis I by Lebl. I was only able to find this, but it is a proof verification using a somewhat different approach.
Let $(X,d)$ be an incomplete metric space. Show that there exists a closed and bounded set $E\subset X$ that is not compact.
I know that incompleteness implies there is some $(x_n)\subset X$ where $(x_n)$ is Cauchy and it does not converge anywhere in $X$. Furthermore, any subsequence of $(x_n)$ does not converge anywhere in $X$. I was thinking of letting $E$ be formed by all of the sequence itself or just some subsequence of $(x_n)$ knowing that $E$ will be bounded. I am just not sure how to proceed showing that this E would be closed and not compact.
Any help or hints are appreciated.

You seem to be heading in the right direction: if $(x_n)$ is Cauchy but not convergent, then its range, ${x_n : n \in \Bbb{N}}$, is a closed and bounded set. To conclude both closedness and non-compactness, it might help to prove that, if $(x_n)$ is Cauchy and $(x_{n_k})$ converges to $x$, then $x_n \to x$ as well.

$E={x_1,x_2,..}$ is closed because it has no limit points.  It is not compact becasue it is not sequentially compact: there is no convergent subsequence of $(x_n)$.
